# How to fire trigger at the end of the month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to know how to fire trigger at the end of the month in MSSql .

Regards,
Giri Bhushan

Comment: Why do you want to do it? What's the underlying problem?

Answer (score 2):

INSERTs and UPDATEs and DELETEs fire triggers. Not schedules.

You'd set up a job in [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) to run a stored procedure or some SQL when needed. Or some external scheduler (Windows scheduler, Quartz.net etc) to run some SQL code.